# Ethically, should you report cheating that you learned of indirectly?

Tags: ethics, cheating

Six classmates and myself have been in the same program for the past 2 years and one of them just informed me of another classmate that sits beside him of cheating on exams, so I informed the professor, and now that person may be kicked out of the program.

Did I do right?

Why did that classmate inform me of the other persons cheating? I felt an ethical obligation, because of the program we are all in too disclose this information to the professor and did not want the burden of knowing on me.

Comment: "*Why did that classmate inform me of the other persons cheating?*" Well, does that classmate hang out here? If not I doubt you'll ever know. Why not just ask him/her?

Comment: The basic question is rather simple: ethically, should you report cheating that you learned of indirectly?  Seems clear to me.  (The "Why" question seems rhetorical and secondary.)  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For many types of moral situations, university rules actually *require* that you inform a superior as soon as you find out yourself, or you are also in violation.  It may be that the classmate who informed you didn't have the civic courage to report it but knew that you did.  It is precisely to break cycles of no one saying anything that the rules are set up in the way I just described.

Or of course it may be that they were lying.  As long as you passed the full information to the professor about how you knew what you knew as well as what you believed you knew, it is now the professor's responsibility and not yours.  If there's anything you *haven't* already told the professor, I'd suggest contacting them again.

Answer (score 3):

> ...one of them just informed me of another classmate that sits beside
>   him of cheating on exams

And why did you believe him? If your classmate told you that the guy behind him is a thief, would you go to the police without checking it? You refer as to your confidant as a "classmate" and not even a friend. Do you believe everything that other people say without checking facts first? How can you be sure that your classmate does not have some kind of animosity or vendetta towards the other student? You should not be that naive.

Regarding ethics, you should go to the professor and tell the absolute truth, i.e., that you did not witnessed first hand the other guy cheating and you naively believed the words of another classmate. Let the burden of truth lie to the one that provided you the information. And next time check your sources first before jeopardizing the future of strangers without solid proof. For all we know, the poor guy might be innocent and you just might be a naive pawn in someone else's vendetta. As is well known in criminal law: "**It is better that ten guilty persons escape than that one innocent suffer**".

Answer (score 1):

Please don't take this negatively, but perhaps "your friend" was too sure about your ethics, and he/she knew that if that information was given to you, it would reach the teacher. So, he/she made *you* do, what he/she believed was ethically correct to do, but didn't want to do it himself/herself, for whatever reasons. Not having first hand info of the ground reality, I/other users on this site can only speculate about those reasons, so I better leave that part out. :)